# Finding Y value corresponding to a particular X

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the precision value corresponding to a cutoff threshold of 0.5, as part of my model evaluation (logistic regression).
I get `numeric(0)` after instead of the Y value.

```
y_hat = predict(mdl, newdata=ds_ts, type="response")

pred  = prediction(y_hat, ds_ts$popularity)  

perfPrc  = performance(pred, "prec")           

xPrc = perfPrc@x.values[[1]]

# Find the precision value corresponds to a cutoff threshold of 0.5 
prc = yPrc[c(0.5000188)] # perfPrc isn't continuous - closest value to 0.5

prc # output is 'numeric(0)' `
```

[image: Precision vs Cutoff]

Comment: what's your yPrc?

Comment: In your `pred` definition you give a single vector as the `newdata` argument. This is bad. You should give it a data frame as you do in the `y_hat` definnition. If that doesn't work, you should share information about how you created the model. The code or the `call` should be sufficient.

Comment: head(yPrc): 

[1]       NaN 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.4000000

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming that you have the model object `mdl` with you, also assuming that your response variable `popularity` has 2 levels `1` (positive) and `0`), by applying the definition of `precision` (you can try some approximate `kNN` based `non-parametric` methods to aggregate precision values at nearby cutoffs present, OR fit curves as `Precision=f(Cutoff)` to find Precision at unknown Cutoff, but that will be approximate again, instead going by definition of precision will give you the correct result):

```
p <- predict(mdl, newdata=ds_ts, type='response') # compute the prob that the output class label is 1
test_cut_off <- 0.5 # this is the cut off value for which you want to find precision
preds <- ifelse(p > test_cut_off, 1, 0) # find the class labels predicted with the new cut off
prec <-  sum((preds == 1) & (ds_ts$popularity == 1)) /  sum(preds == 1) # TP / (TP + FP)
```

**[EDITED}**
Try the following simple experiment with randomly generated data (you can test with your own data).

```
set.seed(1234)
ds_ts <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), popularity=sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE))
mdl <- glm(popularity~x, ds_ts, family=binomial())
y_hat = predict(mdl, newdata=ds_ts, type="response")
pred  = prediction(y_hat, ds_ts$popularity)  
perfPrc  = performance(pred, "prec")           
xPrc = perfPrc@x.values[[1]]
yPrc = perfPrc@y.values[[1]]
plot(xPrc, yPrc, pch=19)
```

[image]

```
test_cut_off <- 0.5 # this is the cut off value for which you want to find precision

# Find the precision value corresponds to a cutoff threshold, since it's not there you can't get this way 
prc = yPrc[c(test_cut_off)] # perfPrc isn't continuous
prc #
# numeric(0)

# workaround: 1-NN, use the precision at the neasrest cutoff to get an approximate precision, the one you have used should work
nearest_cutoff_index <- which.min(abs(xPrc - test_cut_off))
approx_prec_at_cutoff <- yPrc[nearest_cutoff_index]
approx_prec_at_cutoff
# [1] 0.5294118
points(test_cut_off, approx_prec_at_cutoff, pch=19, col='red', cex=2)
```

[image]

The red point represents the approximate precision (it may be exactly equal to the actual precision if we are lucky).

```
# use average precision from k-NN
k <- 3 # 3-NN
nearest_cutoff_indices <- sort(abs(xPrc - test_cut_off), index.return=TRUE)$ix[1:k]
approx_prec_at_cutoff <- mean(yPrc[nearest_cutoff_indices])
approx_prec_at_cutoff
# [1] 0.5294881
points(test_cut_off, approx_prec_at_cutoff, pch=19, col='red', cex=2)
```

[image]

```
p <- predict(mdl, newdata=ds_ts, type='response')
preds <- ifelse(p > 0.5000188, 1, 0)
actual_prec_at_cutoff <-  sum((preds == 1) & (ds_ts$popularity == 1)) /  sum(preds == 1) # TP / (TP + FP)
actual_prec_at_cutoff
# [1] 0.5294118
```

Comment: Thanks. I preferred not calculating it directly and I'm still not sure what went wrong with what I posted.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, only thing is if you want to compute the precision at a specified cutoff value which is not there in the x values, you need to write your own code to approximate it, for example you can you the nearest cutoff value's precision or may be average of k-nearest neighbors.

Comment: if you can share your data (or sample) we can check out.

Comment: updated the post with k-NN method (you are using k=1) and it worked fine on random data, please let me know if it's useful.

Comment: Still i shall vote for computing the precision by definition.

Comment: @InterruptedException  did not the answer to this question help you?

Comment: Dev - I did. I upvoted it, but I can't accept it since it doesn't answer my question. Your solution and elaboration are blessed, nonetheless.

Comment: also if you dont share the data `ds_ts` i can't see your exact problem.